# GZip compression of REST response in Wildfly

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, gzip, wildfly-8

I am writing a REST service to send a list of data in xml format. How do I zip the response.

I see sample code for sending a zip file from filesystem but I want to build the zip part dynamically. First query my database and build the xml data to be sent to the client. This xml data has to be compressed.

Please advise.

```
File file = new File("Test.zip"); // Build this zip dynamically from the xml data and not from sile system
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = Test.zip");
return response.build();
```

Comment: RESTEasy will automatically gzip the response if the client supports it.  See: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html/gzip.html

Comment: gzip and zip are different things. gzip is pure compression, while zip is compression and archival. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this annotation

```
@GZIP
public class SomeController{
}
```

Comment: If you can add some explanation with the code, it would be better.